# how to pass name and address in laravel cashier to stripe?

Tags: stripe-payments, laravel-cashier, laravel-6.2

Iam using stripe through laravel cashier.when using charge method

```
$stripeCharge = $user->charge(100, $paymentMethod,[
          'customer' => 'test',
          'description' => 'test description',
          'amount' => 2000,
          "name"=>"kjdkjdksdsd"
]);
```

I got this error 'Received unknown parameter: name'.
When trying to do transaction without name getting the error 'Export transactions require a customer name and address'.
I tried with shipping address too.

```
"shipping"=> [
            'address'=>[
      "line1"=> "hjkjhjhhjj",
      "line2"=> null,
      "postal_code"=>"44424",
      "state"=> null
            ],
            "name"=> "erferwer"
          ],
```

but still got the same error.
 Anyone can help me with correct format for passing name and address in laravel cashier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like you're trying to create Export charges from India. To do so, there are some [requirements](https://stripe.com/docs/india-exports#valid-charges) you must meet. Note that one of the requirements is a Customer billing address, so you will need to [create a customer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/billing#creating-customers). Shipping address can go there as well, or directly on the `charge`.

Comment: Glad to hear it :)